# Count repetitions of the same number going one after another in a list of numbers

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of numbers of the form `[1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2]` and I need to find the maximum frequency of duplicates going one after the other. In the example above we have overall 7 '2's but the correct answer is 4 because 4 is the sequence of numbers with the greatest length. In the case of `[1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2]`, we have correct answer as 5 even though we have 7 duplicates of 2. 
I tried to use the following code for list for finding duplicates of each number going one after the other:

```
list1 = [1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2]
for number in set(list1):
    count = 1
    list1 = [1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2]
    for idx, i in enumerate(list1):
        if i == number and list1[idx-1] == number:
            count += 1
        else:
            count == 0
    print(number, count)
```

But it does not correctly work as it also includes some of the duplicates from the previous "set of duplicates". 
The output was:

```
1 1
2 6
3 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
ll = [[1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2], [1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2]]
for l in ll:
    counts = [(i, len(list(c))) for i, c in groupby(l)]
    indices = list(map(itemgetter(1), counts))
    idx = indices.index(max(indices))
    print(counts[idx])
```

Where you can get the element with the number of repetitions, depended on the needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby` with `max`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [[1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2], [1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2]]
for i in data:
    print(max((list(v) for _, v in groupby(i)), key=len))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your way of solving it:

```
final_count = []
count = 0
list1 = [1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2]
for idx, i in enumerate(list1):
    if i == 2: 
        count += 1
        if idx == len(list1) - 1: final_count.append(count)
    else:
        final_count.append(count)
        count = 0

result = max(final_count)
print(result)
```